# windows azure diagnostics, load application logs to blob storage

Tags: azure, logging, local-storage, blob

We recently upgraded our application on  azure cloud service from  SDK 2.3 to 2.5 (vs 2013, update 4, using C#),
The application used to write errors to a local storage, and by configuration on the web project (diagnostics.wadcfg), the data was uploaded to the blob storage, 
  How we can do this process now in version 2.5?

we need the data as text on a blob storage and not in a table storage.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? AFAIK, this process should work. Only catch is that it won't work in local emulator with SDK 2.5.

Comment: No errors,But the diagnostics configuration file changed and I can't find how to add a custom application log to the new one?

Comment: It would certainly help if you can share your diagnostics.wadcfg file here.

Comment: <?xml ..>
<Dia..>
  <PublicConfig ...>
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorCo..>
        <DiagnosticInfr../>
        <Directories ..>
          ..
          <DataSources>
            <DirectoryConfiguration containerName="app-logs">
              <LocalResource name="AppLogs" relativePath="."/>
            </DirectoryConfiguration>
          </DataSources>
        </Directories>
      </Diagnosti..>
    </WadCfg>
    <Storage..>Bapp</Storage..>
  </PublicConfig>
  <Priv.. xmlns="..">
    <Sto.. name="bu." endpoint=".." />
  </Priv..>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</Diagn..>

Comment: This should work. Have you tried deploying your code in the cloud? As mentioned in my previous comment, it won't work in local emulator but should work in the cloud.

Comment: Yes, but it's doesnt work